# Stored procedure expects parameter which was not supplied - what's the cause?

Tags: sql-server, ado

[This is my error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYWrI.png)

When I execute this exception occurs.

> Stored procedure or function expects parameter that was not supplied.

This is my code:

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString(); 

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs); 
conn.Open(); 

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_login",conn);  
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",login.UserName.ToString()); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", login.Password); 

i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); 

conn.Close();
```

Comment: This is my codee

string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_login",conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",login.UserName.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", login.Password);
 i=Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
 conn.Close();

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying that you're calling a stored procedure - change your code to:

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString(); 

// put connection and command into "using" blocks
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs)) 
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.sp_login", conn))
{
    // tell your command that it's callign a *stored procedure*! 
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // don't use .AddWithValue - use .Add() and *SPECIFY* your datatype!
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = login.UserName.ToString()); 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = login.Password); 

    // open connection, execute query, close connection
    conn.Open(); 
    i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); 
    conn.Close();
}
```